# How can I set the height of GridView cell based on screen height?

Tags: android, layout, gridview

In my layout I have only eight cells.
I want the cell divide all the space available on the screen. Is this possible?

This is my gridview layout:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dataGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10px"
    android:verticalSpacing="10px"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10px" 
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:gravity="fill" />
```

And this is the item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="6dip"  >   
  <TableRow
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#E00000"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:gravity="left"
          android:textSize="16dip"/>    
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:textStyle="normal"
          android:gravity="right"
          android:textSize="12dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `GridView` is a tricky layout to manipulate to get internal views to fit a specific size like you are attempting. I think it is more appropriate to think of `GridView` as an advanced `ListView` for showing variable-length, scrollable lists like thumbnails in a photo album, as opposed to a "grid." I started down this route when I originally wanted to make a fixed sized grid for a game, but it is really not an appropriate layout for that at all.

Since your grid is always 8 cells, might I suggest using nested `LinearLayout`s (or if you don't want all the cells exactly the same size, the more complex `TableLayout` / `TableRow` combo) instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0"  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <!-- Drop in 4 items here with layout_weight of 0.25 -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <!-- Drop in 4 items here with layout weight of 0.25 -->

    </LinearLayout >
</LinearLayout >
```

This would make a fixed 2x4 grid that always exactly fills the screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, Use PS instead of PX.  This will should allow it to scale to different DPI devices.

Second, to get each cell to be even size you could put a tableView in each cell that contains a clear image.  Set the size of the image with PS (not px).  The table view should allow you to layer the layout ojects in each cell and the clear graphic should keep all of the cells the same size.

I would also remove any padding.

Let us know.

Comment: exuse me but i'm out of internet connection for about three days ... anyway i want the gridview  divide all the space on the screen, based on any android device and this solution isn't good at all; thanks. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should try [android:stretchMode][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode : Defines how columns should stretch to fill the available empty space, if any.