# Grid Calendar not getting full view

Tags: android, android-gridview

> I have grid view calendar in my application.But my grid view is not getting a full view in different screen size.It show only half of the page viewing instead of full view.So i am trying to set the row item's height and width statically in my row.xml file based on the different screen size(Mdpi,Hdpi,Xhdpi).This will be working fine in some types of screen size instead of all screen size.So how do i solve this problem...
>
> Grid Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonframe"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gridprevious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calendar_previous"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#939598"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gridnext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/calendar_next"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutidDays"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sunday" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/monday" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tuesday" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/wednesday" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/thursday" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/friday" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/saturday" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayoutid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#666666" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1.5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:verticalSpacing="1.5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Grid Row Layout:(row.xml)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/griddate"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#5C943B"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridstatusRemainTask"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridstatusFinishTask"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:textColor="#00AEEF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My layout view:
[image]

> I want output the following manner.

[image]

Comment: instead of reinventing the wheel,I would suggest you to grab and modify UI with [this library](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

Comment: Its hard to know by just looking at the XML layout. But just check the parent view if it has any margin or padding for child (GridView) you are placing.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `height` and `width` of the layout of your GridView.

```
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

then, set `height` and `width` of your `GridView` to `fill_parent` as well. Hope this works.

Check following link and modify your `Xml` file. As the code you are using very hard to understand. And set GridView `height` and `width` easily.

[Android Calendar Sample](http://droidwalk.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-calendar-sample.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i already set those width and height but not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Linear Layout try Relative Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@color/reaction_color_selected">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_events_per_day"
        style="@style/calendar_event_style"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="New York" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no srikanth its not working this can be used to only collapsed the two items only...

Comment: hmmm i had tried similar layout Satheesh..try with Relative layout for each row

Comment: try giving fixed width and height for the layout and check once

Comment: but width is changing different mobile compatibility so how to set all the commonly all the mobiles

Comment: then try experimenting weight property

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34035/discussion-between-satheesh-and-srikanth-gr)

Comment: hope this helps u [GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120418/how-can-i-set-the-height-of-gridview-cell-based-on-screen-height) :)